# Should I need to force HTTPS from a mobile app to API?

Tags: security, http, mobile

If my mobile app only makes requests using HTTPS to my API, do I need to worry about forcing HTTPS/disallowing HTTP requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you do. TLS is susceptible to something known as a [Downgrade Attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10493/why-is-tls-susceptible-to-protocol-downgrade-attacks). So be sure to force it to be HTTPS using [HSTS (HTTP Strict Transport Security)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) and disallowing normal HTTP requests in your application server.